# Getting a DeclaringMethod exception (null) when adding Xaml class using typeof

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to add a xaml page to a list collection for navigation. Everytime I'm getting this DeclaringMethod exception:

> ((System.RuntimeType)(new >System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView>(MainMenuItems).Items[0]).PageType).DeclaringMethod

This should worked since it's using typeOf to assign to Type. I'm sure I'm missing something simple but can't see it. Help?

```
 public class MenuItem
{
    public Type PageType { get; set; }
}
public class NavViewModel
{
    public List<MenuItem> MainMenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
    public NavViewModel()
    {
        MainMenuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { PageType = typeof(MyProjectsView) });
    }
}

public sealed partial class NavView : Page
{NavViewModel vm;
    public NavView()
    {
        vm = new NavViewModel();
        hamburgerMenuControl.ItemsSource = vm.MainMenuItems;
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot replicate your described issue.

Comment: What is the actual exception occurring in your code? AFAIK, there doesn't exist any Declaring Method exception.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy all the code in OP. Trying to bind as an itemsource throws a 'System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Added missing code in original post.

Comment: I suggest you better keep the datatype as Page only there is no usercontrol or other types of object you want to store. public Page PageObj { get; set; }

Comment: What is MyProjectsView?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had original used Page but the .Add method threw the precompile error ''MyProjectView' is a type, which is not valid in the given context".   public Page PageType { get; set; } / MainMenuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { PageType = MyProjectsView })

Comment: MyProjectView is a Xaml page.

Comment: You need to also provide the XAML code. And describe what this code for.